# Trying to install lightshot but there's no ./config or ./configure file or *.sh to intall the program

Tags: software-installation, scripts

I want to install lightshot but acutally I am more interested in learning what the issue is of why when I have extracted the lightshot tar.gz file then from what I read all I need to do is find the ./config or ./configure or a script to run and install from there. Then people tell me to go to a readme file but there is one called readme.md but it is gibberish.

Here's what is inside the lightshot folder:

dialogs
lightscreen.pro
lightscreenwindow.h
README.md
updater
images
lightscreen.qrc
lightscreenwindow.ui
sounds
version.pri
LICENSE
lightscreenwindow.cpp
main.cpp
tools
widgets

So what am I missing? Why can't I install?

Also, being a newbie, can I ask why sometimes ./config and why ./configure?

Comment: What is in the readme? A .tar is an archive like a zip file and can contain whatever

Answer (score 0):

The .cpp files suggest to me you have downloaded the source package, which you would have to build.

Assuming we are talking about the same tool, i.e. a screen capture program, then the way to install it on Ubuntu would be this

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wget http://app.prntscr.com/build/setup-lightshot.exe
wine ./setup-lightshot.exe
```